# Insert a line before a particular pattern in solaris

Tags: solaris

I am trying to insert a line before a particular pattern in solaris. I have tried using

> awk '/pattern/{print "new text"}1' filename

But getting

> awk: syntax error near line 1
>   awk: bailing out near line 1

Then I tried using

> sed '/pattern/a new text' filename

and got

> sed: command garbled:

Can anyone please help me regarding this simple but useful command.

Comment: No luck with any of the solutions!

Comment: Sorry, missed an `s`: Try `sed 's/pattern/a new text/'` filename with an additional slash, or `sed 's/pattern/a new text&/'` filename to keep the text matching the pattern.

Comment: oh this is working fine! Thanks a lot for your kind help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed 's/pattern/a new text/' filename
```

or

```
sed 's/pattern/a new text&/' filename
```

to keep the text matching the pattern

Answer (score 0):

On Solaris `awk` refers to the legacy original `awk` utility. To get the standard `awk` features, you need to either call `nawk` (new awk) or `/usr/xpg4/bin/awk` (POSIX awk) with which your script will work just fine.